# What Business Intelligence tool is better for big data visualization QlikeView or QlikSense? Does both the tools provide integration with R?

Tags: bigdata, visualization, business-intelligence, qlikview, qliksense

What Business Intelligence tool is better for big data visualization Qlik View or Qlik Sense? Does both the tools provide integration with R?

Answer (score 1):

Both tools are optimal for Big Data because use the same script language and connectors for that.

The real difference between QlikView and QlikSense is the layout part.